# jQuery access element by id

Tags: jquery

This may be a simple question.
I need to access an html element using jQuery in the following way:

```
var element_ID = "my" + "name" +"xyz";
```

Now I want to access/manipulate the element whose ID I have stored in 'element_ID' as above.

This doesn't work : `$('#element_ID')`

Please let me know the correct way to access the element stored 'element_ID' variable.

-Vijay

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use string concatenation once more...

```
$('#' + element_ID)
```

Comment: If you don't like building strings you can also do `$(document.getElementById(element_ID))` :P

Comment: @alex Oh yeah, that's much more succinct. XP